# Error running flutter project when i use fire base

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I run the flutter project I get this error message:

> Finished with error: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1

firebase_core: ^0.3.4
firebase_ml_vision: ^0.2.1

I use this for dependencies in pubspec.yaml file when I commit these two lines the project runs but if I invoke any one of them, I get this error

Any ideas on how to fix this?

dependencies:

flutter:
    sdk: flutter

image_picker: ^0.6.0
  firebase_core: ^0.3.4
  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.2.1

This is the yaml file

Comment: Can you tell me the complete error?

Comment: Error message is (Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1)

Comment: Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296533/adding-firebase-to-flutter-project-breaks-the-project/58297100#58297100

Comment: Still have the same message i follow the steps you wrote in the question

Comment: Check android/app/build.gradle  flag minifyEnabled. If true- comment this line.